# Check if multiple directories exist in Powershell and then execute command

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using this command to remove multiple files in two different directories:

```
     Remove-Item -path c:\tmp\folder1\*, c:\tmp\folder1\* -Force -Recurse
```

both folders contain some zip files and sub folders which i want te remove

I need to check if those folders (folder1 and folder2) exist and not empty before executing this command. Can't figure it out :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `Get-ChildItem` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6).

Comment: use `Test-Path` to see if the dir exists. do you really care if there is anything in the target dir?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i am running this in ansible playbook so if the directory not exists the task will fail.

Comment: so you cannot use test-path inside the script? ///// you really ought to add that info to your OP - it seems to be an important part of the problem ... [*grin*]

Comment: If you can't use `Test-Path` for some reason I can't think of, you could simply ignore errors on folders that do not exist by writing `Remove-Item -path c:\tmp\folder1\*, c:\tmp\DoesNotExist\* -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. Of course this will also hide errors when there are files in there you may not delete because of lack of permissions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check multiple conditions with an `if` then `-and` the results:

```
if ((Test-Path 'C:\tmp\folder1\*') -and 
    (Test-Path 'C:\tmp\folder2\*') ){
    Remove-Item -path c:\tmp\folder1\*, c:\tmp\folder1\* -Force -Recurse
} else {
    "not all conditions met."
}
```

An explicit `Test-Path` for the folders isn't neccessary as it is implied with items in the folders.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the command "test-path", and then using a | (a pipe) to output a true or false value for proceeding to executing the command that you are using to delete a directory.